# LIKE query in PDO not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

PDO queries run fine, but when i try to use LIKE query it don't work and give error. i know i am doing something wrong, please if anyone can point out where i have gone wrong and how to run the the LIKE query properly.

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: HaiderHassan
 * Date: 9/3/14
 * Time: 9:52 PM
 */
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=houserentsystem;charset=utf8', 'root', 'admin');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
if($_POST['searchFilter']){
    $searchFilter = "%".$_POST['searchFilter']."%";
    echo $searchFilter;
    $stmt = $conn->query("SELECT roomName FROM roomnames WHERE roomName LIKE".$searchFilter);
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $stmt->closeCursor();
    print_r(json_encode($results));
}
```

i have two columns in table(`roomnames`) `roomID` and `roomName`
i want to get the result of data which matches with the posted value.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: I suppose your other "working" queries need to be fixed too.

Comment: @Marek
No thats the only query i needed. wanted that query for sidebar gadget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement should be prepared

```
if($_POST['searchFilter']){
    $searchFilter = $_POST['searchFilter'];
    echo $searchFilter; 
    try {
        $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=houserentsystem;charset=utf8', 'root', 'admin');
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT roomName FROM roomnames WHERE roomName LIKE ?");
        $stmt->execute(array('%'.$searchFilter.'%')); 
        $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        //print_r($results);
        echo json_encode($result);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Comment: used your `$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT roomName FROM roomnames WHERE roomName LIKE ?");
        $stmt->execute(array('%'.$searchFilter.'%'));`
Worked like a charm.
Thanks.

Comment: yes this way you are safe, especially with search queries

Comment: Thankyou, you really saved some of my time.

Answer (score 5):

You have multiple problems:

a) Vulnerable to SQL injection attacks
b) Lacking a space after LIKE, which means you're producing

```
... LIKE%foo%
```

c) Lack of quotes around your search parameter, so even if you did fix b), you'd still have a problem. it should be

```
... LIKE '$searchParameter'
         ^----------------^--- note the quotes
```

Comment: SQL injection no problem, cuz making a sidebar gadget, and only select query was needed for if data exists show. :)
For now they dont care for sql injection and they will have local server.

Answer (score 2):

In this line:

```
    $stmt = $conn->query("SELECT roomName FROM roomnames WHERE roomName LIKE".$searchFilter);
```

1. There has to be a space behind the `LIKE`
2. You need to enclose the string between apostrophs to make it an actual SQL string
3. You ***should definitely*** use [parametrized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), because right now this is a gaping SQL injection hole (what if someone searches for `';delete from roomnames; select '`?)

Comment: You really should not answer with another wrong/incomplete solution.

Comment: Agreed, but you really should not post a vague comment that offers critique but does not point out the error. What did I miss?

Comment: Not good with queries, Sorry.
Just wanted the solution or way how to make it work.
Thankyou for reply.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes You mentioned it in point 3. Instead of just mentioning it, incorporate it into your answer.

Comment: @Marek I don't understand your point. Did you seriously downvote and put a derisive comment here just because I don't write someone's code for them from A to Z, preferring instead to only point them to the right direction and let themselves figure it out from there? Give a man a fish... even the highest voted answer here doesn't give a copy/paste solution.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes I didn't downvote and the comment was not meant to be derisive.

Comment: No harm done then. Your comment came at the same time as the downvote so I (wrongly) assumed you did both. But next time, when posting critique on an answer, elaborate on the reason. We're all here to learn.